# Python string.strip() shows weird behaviour

Tags: python, string

I have a string in the form of `'H:\\Jupyter\\SAF_Prewfdsds\\Testings_05601252\\050_7_150_PYPL.csv'`

I want to use `string.strip('H:\\Jupyter\\SAF_Prewfdsds\\Testings_05601252\\050_7_150_')` so that the output should be `PYPL.csv`.
But the actual output is `YPL.csv`, why? How do I fix that?

Comment: `strip` takes an argument as a *set* of characters that should be stripped off both ends. Could you give a few more examples of desired inputs/outputs?

Comment: Can't you do `string[-8:]`?

Comment: If this is the only string you're working with; `string[-8:]` will work. However if you have multiple strings we would need examples to assist.

Comment: ohh I thought ```strip``` takes a string and removes it when it find that part, yes I can just use ```string[54:]``` (other direction doesn't work because the length varies), I didn't think of that, now I feel dumb, THANKS GUYS

Comment: @NoBody i think you wanted to use `replace`. Check my answer for more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace to achieve what you wanted to do.

```
>>> string.replace('H:\\Jupyter\\SAF_Prewfdsds\\Testings_05601252\\050_7_150_', '')
'PYPL.csv'
```

This will replace the first arg with the second arg

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you want to use string.strip, but if you change your mind, you can slice

```
my_string = 'H:\\Jupyter\\SAF_Prewfdsds\\Testings_05601252\\050_7_150_PYPL.csv'
sliced_string = my_string[-8:]
```

Comment: I'm too slow, suggestion made in comments.